# In javascript, how to select elements in array into another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wanna select one element in array from multiple elements in another array.
The array is as follows.

```
{
    "f": "Book2.csv",
    "v": 0,
    "vs": ["Year", "Month", "Customer_ID", "Collateral", "Exposure_amount"],
    "xs": ["Customer_type", "Region", "Collateral_type", "Collateral_value"],
    "y": 1,
    "x": 0,
    "ys": ["Customer_type", "Region", "Collateral_type", "Collateral_value"]
}
```

I try to get "Customer_type" in "xs" array.

```
var custype = data["xs"]data["x"]
```

but exception has occurred.

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

how can I solve this?

Comment: add `;` in end of the each statement .

Comment: so is it js or php??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Customer_type" is in the zero position in the `data.xs` array, so you'd get it with

```
data["xs"][0]
```

As you seemt to be trying to use the `data["x"]"` property, which is also zero, you'd just do

```
data["xs"][ data["x"] ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
 var custype = data["xs"][0];
```